# .htaccess 301 redirect if page has a trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess

lets say my domain page is
www.website.com/about
and then a user puts 
www.website.com/about/  (a trailing slash) at the end

it returns the same page, great. However search engines may see this as duplicate content as it could be seen as 2 pages.

if the user puts a trailing slash at the end of a page i want them to do a 301 redirect to the correct page.

my .htaccess file looks like this

```
    # Begin cache control #
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1440 minutes"
    ExpiresByType text/html "now plus 1440 minutes"
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|png|bmp|ico|htm|gff|html|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|gcf)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1440 minutes"
    </FilesMatch>


    # End cache control #
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews


    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html image/png image/jpeg image/jpg text/css text/javascript 
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    ## hide .php extension
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Does any one know how I can achieve this as everything im trying will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this rule just before your last rule to remove trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]
```